# How do you make the Xfce Sensors Plugin fit in the Panel

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, plugin, panel, sensors

I want to display two temperatures on top of each other in my panel, but even with the text set to be x-small they won't fit.

There is an option to 'Small Horizontal Spacing' which reduces the gab between temps when placed next to each other, but not one to reduce a vertical gap when they are placed on top of each other.

Here is what it looks like currently:

[image]

This is what it looks like if I remove labels (which I don't want to do):

[image]

And here is how much I have to stretch the panel out by if I do want it to display both temps:

[image]

The panel is set to be 27 row size. This size fits my window theme perfectly, I can afford to go a little bit bigger but not as big as I am currently required to in order to display both temps on top of each other.

I want to be able to either reduce the size of the gap separating the two (and also possibly reduce the gap between the first temp and the top of the panel), or to lower the font even lower so that both fit within the allotted panel size.

I have tried looking at the two config files displayed on the source code repository page but have not been able to work out a solution through there (the solution could be in one of those files and I might have missed it as I'm not exactly a programmer)

So how exactly can I make them both fit together, on top of one another in my panel?

([Originally posted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233348/387157), but I got no responses).

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to ensure that this question doesn't get "Close" votes for cross-posting, please consider deleting the question on AskUbuntu if you got no response there.